Migrated from a weblogic server application to tomEE
I have a javaee application that I migrated from a weblogic server application to tomEE. The problem I have is that it does not pass the BeforeLoginFilter filter when sending the request. This works correctly in weblogic but not in Apache-Tomee-plume-8.0.15. The code of my project is as follows:
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Tomcat JAAS example</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <description>desc</description>
        <display-name>AuthorizationEndpoint</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AuthorizationEndpoint</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.account.myservlet.AuthorizationEndpoint</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>configFile</param-name>
            <param-value>${config.basename}</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuthorizationEndpoint</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/server/authorize</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.account.myservlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>configFile</param-name>
            <param-value>${config.basename}</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProcessLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.account.myservlet.ProcessLoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProcessLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/process-login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>BeforeLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.account.filter.BeforeLoginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>otpUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>/otp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>BeforeLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PreLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.account.filter.PreLoginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>loginCheckUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>/process-login</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PreLoginFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>AuthorizationEndpoint</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
            <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->
            <url-pattern>/process-login</url-pattern>
            <!-- If you list http methods, only those methods are protected -->
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <!-- Default login configuration uses form-based authentication -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

</web-app>

PreLoginFilter.java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PreLoginFilter implements Filter {
    private String loginCheckUrl;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("PreLoginFilter" + "##" + "init");
        this.loginCheckUrl = filterConfig.getInitParameter("loginCheckUrl");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("PreLoginFilter" + "##" + "doFilter");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + loginCheckUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("PreLoginFilter" + "##" + "destroy");
    }
}

BeforeLoginFilter.java
import ir.tamin.account.utils.AuthStatus;
import ir.tamin.account.utils.ServletProperties;
import org.jose4j.base64url.Base64;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BeforeLoginFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreLoginFilter.class);

    private String otpUrl;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) req);
        HttpServletResponse response = ((HttpServletResponse) resp);
        if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null && !request.getUserPrincipal().getName().isEmpty()) {
            if (AuthStatus.PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED == request.getSession().getAttribute(ServletProperties.AUTH_STATUS)) {
                LOGGER.info("session is partially authenticated, so client is being sent to {} for otp processing", otpUrl);
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + otpUrl);
                return;
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("session is authenticated, need not to login");
                String url = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(ServletProperties.ORIGINAL_REQUEST);
                response.sendRedirect(new String(Base64.decode(url)));
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.otpUrl = config.getInitParameter("otpUrl");
    }

}

I expect that after sending the request

request:http://localhost:8080/auth/server/authorize

, first enter the PreLoginFilter filter and then resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + loginCheckUrl); Enter the BeforeLoginFilter filter from the doFilter method. It works properly in Weblog, but it doesn't pass the BeforeLoginFilter filter in Tomee.
